# Pandas to read a excel file from s3 and apply some operation and write the file in same location

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

i am using pandas to read an excel file from s3 and i will be doing some operation in one of the column and write the new version in same location. Basically new version will overwrite the original version.

with csv file i am able to achieve using the below code but not sure of excel(.xlsx). Please can someone help.

```
key = source_path + folder_name + "/" + file_name
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=key)
csv_buf = StringIO()
df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])
df["col1"] = df["col1"] * 100
df.to_csv(csv_buf, index=False)
csv_buf.seek(0)
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucketname, Body=csv_buf.getvalue(), Key=key)
```

i tried to use the same code using read_excel and to_excel getting UnsupportedOperation: seek error.

```
key = source_path + folder_name + "/" + file_name
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=key)
    csv_buf = StringIO()
    df = pd.read_excel(obj['Body'])
    df["col1"] = df["col1"] * 100
    df.to_excel(csv_buf, index=False)
    csv_buf.seek(0)
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucketname, Body=csv_buf.getvalue(), Key=key)
```

Error Message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-298-9363cf7d6609> in <module>
      6         obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=raw_bucket, Key=key)
      7         csv_buf = StringIO()
----> 8         df = pd.read_excel(obj['Body'])
      9         df["patient_ID"] = df["patient_ID"] * 100
     10         df.to_excel(csv_buf, index=False)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    297                 )
    298                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 299             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301         return wrapper

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    334     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
    335         should_close = True
--> 336         io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
    337     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    338         raise ValueError(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine, storage_options)
   1069                 ext = "xls"
   1070             else:
-> 1071                 ext = inspect_excel_format(
   1072                     content=path_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options
   1073                 )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in inspect_excel_format(path, content, storage_options)
    951     ) as handle:
    952         stream = handle.handle
--> 953         stream.seek(0)
    954         buf = stream.read(PEEK_SIZE)
    955         if buf is None:

UnsupportedOperation: seek
```

sample file

s.no  patient_id
1     100
2     200
3     300
4     400
5     500

Comment: to save again as `csv` you should use `to_csv()` instead of `to_excel()`. And to read excel you can use `read_excel()` - and rest should be the same.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry i made a typo in above code and corrected it. I want to read the excel file, apply some operation and overwrite the original version in same .xlsx format. i tried the below code i am getting "UnsupportedOperation: seek error" i couldnt find a working solution. Please could you help.

Comment: you should show it in question. always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I have included the complete error message

Comment: maybe you should first get all data from S3 and put in `StringIO` - `csv_buf = StringIO( obj['Body'].read() )` and later use `csv_buf.seek(0)` and `read_excel(csv_buf)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below solution it worked for me. Now you can directly pass the s3 location of the file.

```
 key = source_path + folder_name + "/" + file_name
    path = "s3://" + bucket_name + "/" + key
    if target_file[num].endswith(".xlsx"):
        df = pd.read_excel(path)
        df["col1"] = df["col1"] * 100
        df.to_excel(path)
    elif target_file[num].endswith(".csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(path)
        df["col1"] = df["col1"] * 100
        df.to_csv(path)
```

Comment: Thanks it is working.